# php curl and download file

Tags: php, curl

I would like to use the invoiz api to download an invoice:
https://app.invoiz.de/api/documentation/#/invoices/download%20InvoiceDocument

my code:

```
// DOWNLOAD INVOICES
$curl = curl_init('https://app.invoiz.de/api/invoice/ID_OF_INVOICE/download');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apiKey . ":" . $secretApiKey); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token->token,
    'accept: application/pdf'
));

$content = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

echo $content shows:

[image]

But I would like to download the pdf file.
How can I realize it?

CURL response:

```
access-control-allow-origin: *  
connection: keep-alive  
content-disposition: attachment; filename="MyFileName.pdf"  content-type: application/pdf  
date: Tue,31 Jan 2023 10:50:24 GMT  
strict-transport-security: max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains; preload  
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

Comment: the api doesn't return a JSON response so ``$invoice = json_decode($content, true);`` doesn't make sense !!

Comment: The content **is** a PDF file. PDFs are binary data.

Answer (score -4):

You must put the header to pdf so that your browser understands that it is a pdf.

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```

Or to force download something like that :

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\"");
```

Comment: kindly, don't add duplicate answers.

Comment: the first example works, but it will only show the file in browser (logically). with your second answer it should be automatically download the file. but where I get the $file? Please look in the response, which I get from the curl (my first post)